# how to set in fixed position i.e. without scrolling <li> element and its child <ul>?

Tags: css

Here is my HTML code.
I want first li #listDomain and a linkChooseDomain in fixed position i.e. without scrolling.

```
<ul>
        <li id="listDomain" style="overflow-x: hidden; height: 525px; display:block">
                        <a id="alinkChooseDomain"><span class="nav-label">Choose Domain</span></a>
         <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input id="txtDomainSearch" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li>select All</li>
        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li>ABC</li>
        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li>JKL</li>
        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li>CDF</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The inner ul is a child of li

Answer (score 0):

### position: fixed;

```
<li id="listDomain" style="overflow-x: hidden; height: 525px; display:block; position: fixed;">
```

---

By the way, your use of white-spacing is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

A slight refactoring of your code, I moved `<a id="alinkChooseDomain"><span class="nav-label">Choose Domain</span></a>` inside of `<div class="input-group">`

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q5p868ez/)